# Сдвиг элемента влево jQuery Sly

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, slider-sly.js

Всем привет!
Вот есть [код](http://jsfiddle.net/9dJfQ/12/).

```js
var sly = new Sly($('.frame.left'), {
    horizontal: 1,
    itemNav: 'basic',
    activateOn: 'click',
    mouseDragging: 1,
    startAt: 0,
    speed: 300,
    activeClass: 'active',
})

sly.on('active', function (eventName, activatedItemIndex) {
    sly.toStart(activatedItemIndex)
})


sly.init();
```

```css
.frame {
    width:170px;
    margin:10px;
    border: inset black 1px
}
.item {
    text-align:center;
    width:30px;
    float:left;
    border-right: inset red 1px
}
.item.placeholder {
    border:none;
}
.active {
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Darsain/sly/master/src/sly.js"></script>
<div class="frame left">
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
        <div class="item">5</div>
        <div class="item">6</div>
        <div class="item">7</div>
        <div class="item">8</div>
        <div class="item">9</div>
        <div class="item">10</div>
        <div class="item "></div>
        <div class="item "></div>
        <div class="item "></div>
        <div class="item "></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как сделать так чтобы элемент автоматически сдвигался влево??? Не нажимая на него!
Заранее всех благодарю. Рассмотрю все варианты. Предлагайте.

Александр

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как вариант так http://jsfiddle.net/9dJfQ/15/. только нужно доработать в плане количества прокруток (чтобы при на последнем элементе сдвиг начинался сначала или по другому) и подсвечивать активный элемент

Comment: Спасибо огромное! ;)
Мне очень помогло. Просто я новичок в jQuery